# javascript es6 import symbols into a namespace

Tags: javascript, d3.js, ecmascript-6

Is it possible to import specific symbols from a ES6 javascript module, but still into a namespace? I'm looking for a combination of: `import * as d3 from 'd3'` which puts imported symbols into the d3 namespace, and `import {select, selectAll} from 'd3-selection'` which avoids importing everything. Ideally I would like something like that:

```
import {select, selectAll} as d3 from 'd3-selection'

d3.select(...)
d3.selectAll(...)
```

Is it possible? I want to keep the usual code syntax of `d3.function` in my code, but also import only the symbols I need.

Comment: when in doubt, [read documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) - if the pattern you want is not there, then it isn't valid - at a pinch ... you could do `import {select, selectAll} from 'd3-selection'; const d3 = {select, selectAll};`

Comment: I've read it but I thought I might be missing something. Coming from other languages this seems like a pretty big oversight not to include such a syntax. So I'd be interested for additional background on this as well.

Comment: a big oversight because it doesn't suit your exact requirements? you can do it in two lines of code - no big deal

Comment: I'd be happy to accept that answer :) javascript is complicated no big deal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform that in two lines of code

```
import {select, selectAll} from 'd3-selection'; 
const d3 = {select, selectAll};
```